# How to run container in container with rancher-desktop>

Tags: containers, containerd, nerdctl

I am running Rancher-Desktop over Ubuntu:22.04, retooling Docker in replacement of Rancher Desktop.

Every works perfectly except, in the past where Docker allows me to run DinD (Docker in Docker) by mounting the docker.sock `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` then inside my running container  e.g. `docker run --rm -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ${SOMEIMAGEWITHDOCKER} /bin/bash`, I could talk dockerd inside the container, similar to whats is working on my host machine.

I thought the same can be done for Rancher's Desktop containerd, if I could mount the cointainerd socket to an image which contains `nerdctl` tool.

However, I've searched and can't seem to find a way in doing so.

- The default "/run/k3s/containerd/containerd.sock" does not exist in Ubuntu nor I can find anything named `containerd.sock`